# jQuery if and logic

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery toolbar, the basic functionality is:

1. Hover: Background change to defined value & add .active class
2. OnClick: Move the icon down 4px, and change background of the toolbar to that of the element

What I would like to do move the icon down 4px when it has the class 'active' applied, however also remove the onclick event?

Somehow I need an 'IF' statement in my jQuery for the Onclick event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the if part you could use the active class as a flag..

so inside the click handler

```
if ( !$(this).hasClass('active') ) {
  // do what you want
}
```

which translates to "if the clicked element does not have the `active` class assigned then do what you want to do" ...